# How to compare two arrays of objects in JavaScript using a key in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

How to compare two arrays of objects in JavaScript using a key in object.I have two result sets like this. Is it possible to do something like this in JavaScript? or Lodash?

```
    // Array 1
        [
            { Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer 1" },
            { Id: "3", display: "Muhammed 1" },
        ]
    
    // Array 2
        [
            { Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer" },
            { Id: "1", display: "Muhammed" },
            { Id: "2", display: "Ravi" },
            { Id: "3", display: "Ajmal" },
            { Id: "4", display: "Ryan" }
        ]
    
    
    The final result I need is - same id in array 2 should be replaced with corresponding id in array 1 – the final result should be like this:
    
    [
            { Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer 1" },
            { Id: "1", display: "Muhammed" },
            { Id: "2", display: "Ravi" },
            { Id: "3", display: "Ajmal 1" },
            { Id: "4", display: "Ryan" }
        ]
```

Comment: In your final result, shouldn't your second last object be: `{ Id: "3", display: "Muhammed 1" }` due to Array 1 having an object with id 3 and display of `"Muhammed 1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from your arr1, which is keyed by the object `Id`s and stores the display of each object as its value. The map will have the following shape:

```
{
  "0" => "Jamsheer 1"
  "3" => "Muhammed 1"
}
```

You can then use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `arr2` to change the display property of a given object if its `Id` appears in the Map you made. If the `Id` does appear, take the value from the Map and use that as the display, if it doesn't use the original display value for the object.

See example below:

```js
const arr1 = [{ Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer 1" }, { Id: "3", display: "Muhammed 1" },];
const arr2 = [{ Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer" }, { Id: "1", display: "Muhammed" }, { Id: "2", display: "Ravi" }, { Id: "3", display: "Ajmal" }, { Id: "4", display: "Ryan" }];

const arr1Map = new Map(arr1.map(o => [o.Id, o.display]));
const res = arr2.map(({Id, display}) => ({
  Id,
  display: arr1Map.get(Id) || display
}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

If you have other properties other than just `display`, you can store objects in your map instead:

```js
const arr1 = [{ Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer 1", foo: 1, bar:2 }, { Id: "3", display: "Muhammed 1", baz: 3 },];
const arr2 = [{ Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer" }, { Id: "1", display: "Muhammed" }, { Id: "2", display: "Ravi" }, { Id: "3", display: "Ajmal" }, { Id: "4", display: "Ryan" }];

const arr1Map = new Map(arr1.map(o => [o.Id, o]));
const res = arr2.map(o => arr1Map.get(o.Id) || o);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
  var arr1 = [
            { Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer 1" },
            { Id: "3", display: "Muhammed 1" },
        ]
    var arr2 =
   
        [
            { Id: "0", display: "Jamsheer" },
            { Id: "1", display: "Muhammed" },
            { Id: "2", display: "Ravi" },
            { Id: "3", display: "Ajmal" },
            { Id: "4", display: "Ryan" }
        ]
    
    


function comparer(otherArray){
        return function (current) {
            return otherArray.filter(function(other) {
                return other.Id === current.Id
            }).length===0;
        }
    }


var compArray = arr2.filter(comparer(arr1));
compArray.map(i=> arr2.push(i));
console.log(arr2);
```

you can use [_.concat()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#concat)  and  [_.unionWith()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unionWith) functions on [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
var array = [1];
var other = _.concat(array, 2, [3], [[4]]);
 
console.log(other);
// => [1, 2, 3, [4]]
 
console.log(array);
// => [1]


var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
 
_.unionWith(objects, others, _.isEqual);
// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }]
```